# Extract tags of a place on Foursquare

Tags: api, tags, foursquare

I could not find any ways of extracting the tags of a place on Foursquare.

I also found that there are ways for a user to add tags to a place.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are a deprecated feature and I wouldn't recommend relying on it for anything.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for extracting the tags of a place. Is there any API available for this.